# Laravel You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting row's column randomly to seed database, using eloquent :

```
$physician = SelectOption::where('select_option_group_id', 1)->pluck('name')->random();
```

it works if data exists in select_options table. But if it does not exists, it gives an error :

> You requested 1 items, but there are only 0 items available.

I want to leave it empty, if it's empty.

Comment: That's because you're literally trying to random a result that doesn't exist. All you need to do is verify with an if statement, either count($physician) > 0  or empty($physician) or  any method that you'd want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if collection is not empty prior doing `random()`:

```
$collection = SelectOption::where('select_option_group_id', 1)->pluck('name');
if (!$collection->isEmpty()) {
    $physician = $collection->random();
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is 1 in random method ?

Comment: Number of items to be returned. But using 1 is actually pointless, so I removed it now. See `random()` sources [here](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Collection.php#L1174) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Use `inRandomOrder()` instead:

```
$physician = SelectOption::where('select_option_group_id', 1)->inRandomOrder()->first();
$name = is_null($physician) ? 'No data available' : $physician->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your seeder or the date of your migration file. The migrations file is executing by date ex: 20220429_16_43_02_create_order_table.php. So, if you have 20220416_.... after 20220429_.... that throw the exception.

Solution: Change (rename) the date of the file.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to expand on this thought? What are they checking for in terms of the order or the date of the migration file? What would be values that would lead to this result?